# Find out where CMake searches (and why)

Tags: cmake

Suppose I write this in a CMake file:

```
find_path(ISL_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES isl)
```

How do I find out where CMake searches to find a library named `isl`, and WHY it it searching these paths?

Non-solutions:

1. `strace -e file -f cmake`. This certainly tells me where CMake is probing (along with a lot of irrelevant extra information), but it doesn't tell me why CMake has decided to look in a particular directory.
2. Read the [`find_path` documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/find_path.html). This is a bit better: combined with `ccmake`, I can form hypotheses about what is being probed and then check and see if the variables line up. But this is not enough, for a few reasons: (1) I've noticed that CMake will search in the include/library directories associated with the *CMake installation itself* (so, for example, if I used conda to install CMake, the conda-distributed CMake will automatically pick up conda includes/libraries). I don't see anything in the documentation which indicates this ought to happen. (2) CMake will only give information about persistent variables, and not transient ones like `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` which are quite important to resolution.
3. Use `--debug-output` or `--trace`. These seem to give too much information and I don't know what to look for.

What I want is a way to make CMake tell me each directory it is looking in when it executes a `find_path`, why it is considering that directory, and which one it eventually decides fits. Is this at all possible?